# Batch transaction in Near

Tags: nearprotocol

One of core concept of how Near work is transaction is not atomic (for external call in a transaction). i did asked one question (["Atomic-transaction" in NEAR protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166821/atomic-transaction-in-near-protocol)) about this topic here.

However, there still a thing that i want to ask. In there, one transaction may have many actions. This method signAndSendTransaction (docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-cookbook#batch-transactions) can be used to send batch transaction.

I did try it and it give me interesting result:

- if i send 2 actions, which one of them will be failed, the whole transaciton will not process -> this sound like a atomic way for me if i can do it with external call in one of the action too. so i came with the 2nd try.
- if i send 2 actions, one action will make the contract call external transcation (which all valid), and the second action will be failed, it will always process the failed action first lead to fail the whole transaction and not come to the external call anyway.

My question here is that, how does these transaction work excactly? does Near behave differently in these batch transaction that can atomic revert all?
if i can find a way to call external contract in one of the action, will the external transaction be reverted with the batch transaction too?